# Strange enum behavior in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have the following enum(it is truncated to make the examples cleaner)

```
class ObjectNames(enum.Enum):
    full = 'full'
```

And this one:

```
class ObjectPoses(enum.Enum):
    front = 'front'
    left = 'left'
    right = 'right'
```

This two enums are tied with the following relation:

```
class ObjectNamePoseMatcher:
    match = {
        ObjectNames.full: [ObjectPoses.front, ObjectPoses.right, ObjectPoses.left],
}
```

So it basically creates a relation between an ObjectName and a pose.
This is the setup. At some point my code fails with `KeyError` when trying to make `ObjectNamePoseMatcher.match` lookup. Specifically, it fails with this error message:

`KeyError: <ObjectNames.full: 'full'>`
It fails here:

`ObjectNamePoseMatcher.match[self._object_name]`,

however

```
>>self._object_name
<ObjectNames.full: 'full'>
```

and

`>>ObjectNamePoseMatcher.match
{<ObjectNames.full: 'full'>: [<ObjectPoses.front: 'front'>, <ObjectPoses.right: 'right'>, <ObjectPoses.left: 'left'>]}`

So the key is there. This is strange so I executed the following snippet:

```
for k,v in ObjectNamePoseMatcher.match.items():
    print(k,k==self.object_name)
    print(hash(k)==hash(self.object_name))
    print(id(k)==id(self.object_name))
    print(id(type(k))==id(type(self.object_name)))
```

And this results in:
`ObjectNames.full False True False False`
So `ObjectNames.full` and `self._object_name` have the same hash, but different types, id and type ids. But hash is the same.

After this I went to the very first place where `self._object_name` field is set. Executed the same snippet again, got the same result. I executed this snippet after this line:

`d.object_name = ObjectNames.full`
However if at this breakpoint I re-execute this line

`d.object_name = ObjectNames.full`
and then execute the aforementioned snippet I get the following output:

`ObjectNames.full True True True True`
So now hash, ids and type ids match! For no reson, I just re-executed the same line after stopping at breakpoint.

What could possibly go wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)?

Comment: @Georgy last time I was trying to do that, I could not achieve the same behavior in an isolated env.

Comment: then something else is going on, that's the point of making a MCVE -- to pin down the source of error

Comment: Sounds like you are reimporting or redefining your enums somehow.  Check for circular imports, and for importing the same module using different paths.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want `IntEnum` not `Enum`. `IntEnum`s compare by integer values and so by transitivity to other unrelated enumerations. You're clearly expecting instances of `ObjectNames` and `ObjectPoses` to be comparable and I don't think `Enum`s work like that.